# Cannot see published Word Web Add-in in 'My Organisation' Tab

Tags: office-addins, office-js

I have been trying to get the [Word Add-in samples](https://dev.office.com/code-samples) and my own Word Web Add-in running on my O365 instance. I can build all the solutions locally and run/debug. The buttons on the ribbon appear, and the task pane (web site) is shown, all as expected.

However, if I follow the instructions to publish to my O365 account I can't seem to get the add-in to load. I do the following:

1. Publish the associated add-in web site to Azure, and make sure the homepage loads OK
2. Login to my O365 account as the admin account
3. Select the **Admin** button
4. Select **Setting> Service & add-in** and press the **Upload add-in**. I then upload the published add-in manifest (with the correct URL for the Azure hosted add-in website). This publishes OK, and I can grant rights to everyone or specific users (I tried both).

Problem is

- If I open the hosted version of Word, or the desktop Word 2016 version (whilst connected O365 account) I don't see the buttons on the ribbon or task pane
- Also if I access **Word > Insert > Office Add-ins** the **My Organsiation** tab is empty - I would have expected to see the add-ins I had just published. It just says **your administrator has not installed web add-in for your organization**

I assume I must have missed something obvious, given the web is not people complaining of this problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with Richard on this matter and we found the solution. In order to see the Office 365 tab in the add-ins tab you need to be running Office 365 - version - 16.0.7341.2021. Once we installed this version of office the tab appeared and the add-in could be viewed and used.

Comment: Yes it turns out it was the version. Not sure of it is simple newer version, or that the version that worked was downloaded from 0365

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the add-in isn't be installed anywhere. A problem with your manifest file is a likely cause here. Try uploading the manifest directly inside Word Online: Insert > Add-ins > My Organization > Upload a manifest

[image]

If that fails too then it's definitely a problem with the manifest: check that it conforms to the schema and is configured for the right set of APIs and hosts to work in the Office clients that you're testing.

Comment: i am not sure thats an issue, if the O365 Admin tool reported success while deploying...

Comment: Yes it reports success so I don't think there is a manifest issue. If I introduce an error in the manifest it does reject the add-in as you would expect. 

Also if I use the 'upload my add-in' with the same manifest it is uploaded successfully and works.

Looks to be a publishing issue as opposed to a bad manifest

Answer (score 0):

FYI the add-ins deployed using the Office 365 Admin page show up in a different tab. There should be a OFFICE 365  tab on the insertion dialog and your add-in should be there. Try hitting on the Refresh button and see if it shows up.

Also please provide the build where your Office client is, depending on the build you will see the add-in only on the Office 365 tab, or both in the tab and also the actual Ribbon buttons.

thanks!

Comment: I can’t find the OFFICE 365 tab on the insertion dialog or in the admin add-in area. Have I failed to enable something on O365?

Comment: then most probably its the client you are using. what is the build number?

Comment: We are seeing the lack of add-ins option on both the hosted version of Word in O365

As to the desktop version it is Word 2016 16.04417.1000